# Classify image lines as thick or thin, black or white?

Tags: vb.net, line, barcode

I'm doing some research on code 39 barcodes and replicating this in vb.net.

its realy easy, but that writing the barcode. Naturally I want to also read barcodes with my vb.net application. given that I have saved the image to .jpg is theer a way for VB.net to distingush between the following?

Thick black lines,
Narrow black lines
Thick White lines
Narrow white lines?

Comment: Can you post your code till now or elaborate more?

Comment: Its simple draw lines I have no code as yet for that havent gotten round to that...

Comment: Real barcodes are never stored in jpeg files.  They are invariably printed on paper and require hardware to get their info into a computer.  Like a barcode scanner, which already knows how to read the code.  A camera if you are doing it wrong, a QR code is much better for those.  Focus on the way they are actually going to be used and avoid reinventing a wheel.

Comment: That's all well and said, in many retrospects I agree, however I am limited to the resources I have. Software is still software wether it be on a pc or scanning device or phone. Which is probably the closest towards what im looking for how to achive this like they do on mobile phones